# asp.net GridView and ajax control -AsyncFileUpload

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have an AsyncFileUpload control and a gridView on my asp.net webform
After uploading the file,I am trying to load my gridview with the list of uploaded files

But showing the list of uploaded files to the gridview is not working .
When I debug I can see expected data just before binding to the gridView.
But I cannot see the gridview with the list of uploaded files .Please help

pasted below is  my webform and my cs file

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="test.WebForm2" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" 
    Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
         <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <cc1:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" Width="400px" runat="server" 
OnClientUploadError="uploadError" OnClientUploadStarted="StartUpload" 
OnClientUploadComplete="UploadComplete" 
CompleteBackColor="Lime" UploaderStyle="Modern" 
ErrorBackColor="Red" ThrobberID="Throbber" 
onuploadedcomplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" 
UploadingBackColor="#66CCFF" OnDataBinding="AsyncFileUpload1_DataBinding" />
    </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Style="font-family: Arial; 
    font-size: small;"></asp:Label>


        </div>
              <div class="width100pc floatLeft">
                <asp:GridView ID="grdAttachments" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="0" OnRowDeleting="grdAttachments_RowDeleting"
                    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" EmptyDataText="No attachments to show" Width="100%" OnLoad="grdAttachments_Load" OnRowDataBound="grdAttachments_RowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" ItemStyle-CssClass="displayNone"
                            HeaderStyle-CssClass="displayNone" FooterStyle-CssClass="displayNone" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="File name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-CssClass="width100pc"
                            ItemStyle-CssClass="width100pc" DataField="FileUpload" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="UploadedFullFileName" HeaderText="UploadedFullFileName"
                            ItemStyle-CssClass="displayNone" HeaderStyle-CssClass="displayNone" FooterStyle-CssClass="displayNone" />
                        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" DeleteText="Remove" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function uploadError(sender, args) {
        document.getElementById('lblStatus').innerText = args.get_fileName(),
            "<span style='color:red;'>" + args.get_errorMessage() + "</span>";
    }

    function StartUpload(sender, args) {
        document.getElementById('lblStatus').innerText = 'Uploading Started.';
    }

    function UploadComplete(sender, args) {
        var filename = args.get_fileName();
        var contentType = args.get_contentType();
        var text = "Size of " + filename + " is " + args.get_length() + " bytes";
        if (contentType.length > 0) {
            text += " and content type is '" + contentType + "'.";
        }
        document.getElementById('lblStatus').innerText = text;
    }

</script>
```

Pasted below is the  CS  file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace test
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
        {
            string uniquePath = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fileUploadPath"].ToString(), Session.SessionID);

            if (AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                //string strPath = uniquePath + Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
                //AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(strPath);
                AddNewARowToGrid();
            }
        }

        public void AddNewARowToGrid()
        {
            DataTable dtAttachments = new DataTable();
            int rowNumber = 1;
            string uploadedFullFileName = string.Empty;

            if (ViewState["CurrentATable"] != null)
            {
                dtAttachments = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentATable"];
                rowNumber = dtAttachments.Rows.Count + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                dtAttachments.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
                dtAttachments.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FileUpload", typeof(string)));
                // dtAttachments.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));
                dtAttachments.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UploadedFullFileName", typeof(string)));
            }

            try
            {
                string uniquePath = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fileUploadPath"].ToString(), Session.SessionID);
                if (!Directory.Exists(uniquePath))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(uniquePath);
                uploadedFullFileName = Path.Combine(uniquePath, AsyncFileUpload1.FileName);
                AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(uploadedFullFileName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                               return;
            }

            DataRow drNewRow = dtAttachments.NewRow();

            drNewRow["RowNumber"] = rowNumber;
            drNewRow["FileUpload"] = AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
            //drNewRow["Description"] = txtDescription.Text;
            drNewRow["UploadedFullFileName"] = uploadedFullFileName;

            dtAttachments.Rows.Add(drNewRow);

            // txtDescription.Text = string.Empty;

            ViewState["CurrentATable"] = dtAttachments;
            Session["CurrentATable"] = dtAttachments;

            BindDataGrid(grdAttachments, dtAttachments);
        }
        private void RemoveNewARowToGrid(string rowNumber)
        {
            if (ViewState["CurrentATable"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentATable"];
                DataRow rowToDelete = null;

                if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dtCurrentTable.Rows)
                    {
                        if (int.Parse(row["RowNumber"].ToString()) == int.Parse(rowNumber))
                        {
                            rowToDelete = row;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (rowToDelete != null)
                    {
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows.Remove(rowToDelete);

                        ViewState["CurrentATable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count == 0)
                            LoadEmptyAttachmentSection();
                        else
                            BindDataGrid(grdAttachments, dtCurrentTable);
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        private void BindDataGrid(GridView grd, DataTable dataTable)
        {
            if (null != Session["CurrentATable"])
            {
                dataTable = (DataTable)Session["CurrentATable"];
            }
            grdAttachments.DataSource = dataTable;
            grdAttachments.DataBind();

        }
        private void LoadEmptyAttachmentSection()
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dtAttachments = new DataTable();
                BindDataGrid(grdAttachments, dtAttachments);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return;
            }
        }
        protected void grdAttachments_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            RemoveNewARowToGrid(grdAttachments.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text);
        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AysncFile upload performs the async, and that works ok. What you are doing is binding to a grid that is not being updated because there is NO WAY for it to re-render. It's not in an update panel. You essentially bound the grid in the background, from a completely different request, hence ASYNC.

Drop the grid in an update panel and call update on it after the file is finished and you've re-bound your grid.